# How can I authenticate to Microsoft Graph if my application uses Azure "Easy Auth"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to perform searches for basic user information on Azure Active Directory in an established ASP.NET MVC application using the Microsoft Graph SDK. Having found no mention of using these two together, and my own attempts at implementations failing, I'm wondering if someone else has done this, or if it is known to be impossible.

Currently our application is hosted on an Azure App Service (`xyz.azurewebsites.net`) that is configured to ensure that all requests are authenticated before accessing the app. I understand this to be called "Easy Auth", as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) or [here](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/).

As a test, I more or less followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet?tutorial-step=1), understanding that it was geared for an Azure Active Directory App Registration. I added a barebones controller to the project that called another authentication challenge like so:

```
public void Index()
{
    // Signal OWIN to send an auth request to Azure
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
        OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

The authentication challenge can be completed successfully (even though the user is authorized through `xyz.azurewebsites.net` already). Inspecting the response when the challenge is completed shows I do get a `code` response in the form data. However, the code that is expected to execute and handle a successful authentication never does so (it's shown at the bottom of this post).

Essentially, the current flow is this:

1. User navigates to `xyz.azurewebsites.net`
2. `xyz.azurewebsites.net` sees that the user is not authenticated and takes them to `login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize`
3. User enters their credentials for AAD and signs in, landing on the root page of `xyz.azurewebsites.net`

Everything beyond this point is testing

4. For testing, I navigate to `xyz.azurewebsites.net/signin`, where the above `Index()` method is triggered (confirmed with remote debugging)
5. The challenge redirects me to `login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` and I enter credentials again
6. After successfully logging in, I'm redirected to `xyz.azurewebsites.net` and informed that "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." The method I expect to encounter upon successfully authenticating is never triggered (confirmed with remote debugging)
7. After navigating to other locations in the site, I can access those pages, suggesting that I'm still authenticated with "Easy Auth". My method to test whether I also have access to Microsoft Graph fails.

For testing, what I would like to see happen is that the user enters credentials again, is redirected to the home page successfully, and have controllers be able to access Microsoft Graph somehow.

**Ideas**

Some ideas for what could be preventing success:

- It's possible that what I'm asking for simply cannot be done and we'll have to attack this from another angle.
- I think that the permission denied error outlined in step 6 is due to the callback from the Graph challenge not including the access token that's usually added to the request headers by Easy Auth. Thus, subsequent requests would be intercepted by Easy Auth and work, but because the initial callback failed the code that is expected to execute on a successful challenge is not hit.
- If possible, the app service may need to be configured to return access tokens for Microsoft Graph.

**OWIN Startup Code**

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Notifications;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using xyz.Utilities;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(xyz.Startup))]

namespace xyz
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureActiveDirectoryAppId"];
        private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureActiveDirectoryAppSecret"];
        private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureActiveDirectoryRedirectUri"];
        private static string graphScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureActiveDirectoryGraphScopes"];

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            // This executes upon startup and configures the app.
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = appId,
                    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
                    Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false // May need to be changed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters?view=azure-dotnet
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications 
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
                    }
                }
           );
        }

        private Task OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();
            throw new System.Exception("Authentication Failed"); // This may need to be changed to redirect the user so they can try again.
        }

        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            // This function does not execute once authentication is complete through /SignIn


            var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                                                               .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                                                               .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                                                               .Build();

            var signedInUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
            var tokenStore = new SessionTokenStore(idClient.UserTokenCache, HttpContext.Current, signedInUser);

            string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');
            var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, notification.Code).ExecuteAsync();

            User userDetails = await GraphUtility.GetUserDetailAsync(result.AccessToken);

            string email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userDetails.Mail) ? userDetails.UserPrincipalName : userDetails.Mail;

            var cachedUser = new CachedUser()
            {
                DisplayName = userDetails.DisplayName,
                Email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userDetails.Mail) ? userDetails.UserPrincipalName : userDetails.Mail
            };

            tokenStore.SaveUserDetails(cachedUser);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very strange to login twice. App Service passes user claims to your application by using special headers. For ASP.NET 4.6 apps, the **ClaimsPrincipal** is automatically set with the appropriate values.

Some example headers include:

- X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME
- X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID

If you just want to [acess user claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims), you can use this way.

If you need to call additional graph apis, you can also [get the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#retrieve-tokens-in-app-code) in the request header.